# CComPtr and reference count

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, com, atl, direct2d

I am using objects of type [CComPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ezzw7k98.aspx). But I am having some memory leak problems. In particular, I have the following code:

```
CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> bitmap = create_bitmap(bitmapSize);
auto n = count_ref((ID2D1Bitmap*)bitmap);
```

Where:

```
template<class Interface>
ULONG count_ref(Interface* pInterface) noexcept
{
    if (pInterface)
    {
        pInterface->AddRef();
        return pInterface->Release();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And:

```
ID2D1Bitmap* create_bitmap(const D2D1_SIZE_U& size)
{
    ID2D1Bitmap* bitmap;
    CreateBitmap(&bitmap);

    return bitmap;
}
```

I was expecting a value of `n` equal to 1 but it is actually equal to 2. Why the reference count of my `CComPtr` is not 1?

Am I using my `CComPtr` object properly?

And when the process terminates I get the following memory leak:

```
An interface [072B1F50] was created but not released. Use 'dps 072B1F20' to view its allocation stack.
Object type: ID2D1Bitmap
    Device-dependent size: 1000 x 600
    Device-independent size: 1000.00 x 600.00
    Format: DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM
    Alpha mode: D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED
    Outstanding reference count: 1

D2D DEBUG ERROR - Memory leaks detected.
```

Comment: Take ownership of the interface pointer with CComPtr::Attach().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `CComPtr` you rarely need to use raw interface pointer types.

You can make it this way, for example:

```
CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> create_bitmap(const D2D1_SIZE_U& size)
{
    CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> bitmap;
    CreateBitmap(&bitmap); // Declared as CreateBitmap(ID2D1Bitmap**);
    return bitmap;
}

CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> pBitmap = create_bitmap(...);
...
```

CComPtr class will manage references accurately along the way you pass the pointers: local variable, return value, new local value. Optimizing compiler in Release builds also removes some of the excessive AddRef/Releases too, so you don't need to worry much about them.

Answer (score 3):

When you construct CComPtr from pointer it will share ownership of this pointer and increment reference count. To take ownership of pointer without incrementing reference count use [CComPtr::Attach method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td098k1d.aspx#ccomptrbase__attach).

```c++
CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> bitmap;
bitmap.Attach(create_bitmap(bitmapSize));
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of issues with this code.

Issue one is minor but it can lead to a lot of misunderstanding. `AddRef()` and `Release()` are [not actually required to return any sensible values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30704345/57428). So it's good they return the actual reference count but you cannot rely on this every time. So basically your `count_ref()` function is naive and unreliable.

Now assuming that `Release()` returns the real reference count it's clear that `create_bitmap()` returns an object which already has it's reference count set to one. Then `CComPtr` calls `AddRef()` and reference count changes to 2. Then when `CComPtr` goes out of scope its destructor calls `Release()` and then there're no more pointers to the object and it gets leaked.

The solution to the later problem would be to use `CComPtr::Attach()` to just take ownership of the object returned by `create_bitmap()` without having `AddRef()` called once again:

```
CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> bitmap;
bitmap.Attach(create_bitmap(bitmapSize));
```

that would make code work but it's not very clear and perhaps a bit harder to maintain than necessary. If you can afford changing `create_bitmap()` signature then it'd be better to change it so that it returns `CComPtr` as suggested in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43414170/57428). This makes it clear that the caller must take ownership of the object to anyone seeing the function signature and there's no need to use separate calls to `Attach()`.